# Sitecore Identity Server on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, identity-server

I need some help to **configure the KeyVault** connection string for **Azure App Service** and **Sitecore Identity Service**.

Sitecore Identity Server is based on aspnet core and the connection string settings are configured differently from asp.net app. For Asp.Net App i just added the connection string in the following format into the Azure App Service Configuration tab and it worked.

```
Name: <<Name of the connection string. This can be web, core or master>>
Value: @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<<KeyVault Identifier>>
```

I need to find similar solution for Sitecore Identity App. I have added the image to reflect how connection strings are defined in Sitecore Identity Server.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this isn't possible at the moment in Sitecore 9.1. The code needs to read environment variables like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2016/08/10/working-with-azure-app-services-application-settings-and-connection-strings-in-asp-net-core/) but I don't see that anywhere when I dotPeek in `Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.ConfigureSitecore`.

You could probably request a patch for this from Sitecore Support.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply, I haven't requested the patch but left the puzzle unsolved as we went with Azure AD integration.

Comment: @TechLearner, even in Azure AD we need to provide a connection string Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml placed in \wwwroot\identityserver\Config\production. How did you manage to encrypt or add an environment variable