# How to set the Identity server certificate using Azure KeyVault?

Tags: azure, paas, identity-server, certificate

We are using the Azure KeyVault to store the certificate for our Sitecore setup. This is working fine on the current 9.0 environment. However, we are upgrading to 10.2 and this introduces the Sitecore Identity server. This requires the certificate thumbprint in the
`Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file and we've seen no solution on how to get this to work with the KeyVault.

The certificates are changed every 3 months, so we don't want this to be a manual process. I found this (same) question [Sitecore Identity Server on Azure App Service](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/19350/237) from a few years ago with the same issue on a 9.1 version where apparently it was not possible. As we are a few years further and things might have changed I wanted to ask (again) as this seems like setup which is not that uncommon.

Has anyone any idea or experience with using the KeyVault and the Identity Server?

Comment: Identity Server started to support configuration via environment variables with SC 10.0, so you should be able to setup an environment variable for the certificate thumbprint with the `Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateThumbprint` key. I haven't used it with KeyVault integration though, so you might need to try it from here.